# Displaying a variable amount of lines in a ggplot shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

`hola` I'm stuck on something. I am creating a ggplot2 Shiny app, where the user can select the amount of variables that are displayed in the line chart.  I used the argument Multiple for selectInput, although the app crashed when more than one variables are selected, getting the error:

```
Warning: Error in .subset2: subscript out of bounds
```

Here is the [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QB2IcMRASRG6v5c5qtLNwmO6LnXLQihiaTVaaxxxU3s/edit?usp=sharing)

server:

```
  library(shiny) 
  library(googlesheets)
  library(reshape2)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(scales)
  #google authorization, token storage, file acquiztion and assignment


  myData_off <- melt(ridership_hour_off, id.vars = "time")  
  dat_off <- myData_off[myData_off$time != "Total",]
  dat_off$time_ <- as.POSIXct(paste(dat_off$time), origin = "7:00 AM", format = "%I:%M %p", tz = "UTC")
  dcast_off <- dcast(dat_off, time_~variable)

  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      monthBy_off <- input$month
      trick_off <- dcast_off[[monthBy_off]]
    output$plot_off <- renderPlot({
           O <-ggplot(data = data.frame( x = dcast_off$time_, y = trick_off), aes(x=x,y=y)) +

           geom_line(size = 2, alpha = 0.75) +
           geom_point(size =3, alpha = 0.75) +

          ggtitle("Boarding the Bus Ridership December 2015") +
          labs(x="Time",y="Count")+
          theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=32, hjust=0.5)) +
          theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22))+
         theme_classic()
        O
        })

      })

    })
```

UI:

```
  library(shiny)
  vars <- list("December" = "dec",
            "January" = "jan",
            "February" = "feb",
            "March" = "mar",
            "April" = "apr",
            "May" = "may",
            "June" = "jun",
            "July" = "jul",
            "August" = "aug",
            "September" = "sep",
            "October" = "oct",
            "November" = "nov")
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Cross Acton Transit"),
    titlePanel("Data Dashboard"),
    # Your input selection
    sidebarPanel(
       selectInput("month", "Select plot", vars, selected = "apr", multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    # Show the selected plot
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot",
                 plotOutput("plot_off")
        )
      )
    )
  ))
```

Thank you for any input

Comment: From my research, I think that maybe I need a reactive expression instead of observe. Swapping them out didn't work.

Comment: Do you want a plot with different lines per month?

Comment: yes, I want to choose which lines are and are not on the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from `dcast_off[[monthBy_off]]` which only works with one single value while `input$month` contains a vector of charater because of `multiple=TRUE` that allows selecting more than one month.

You'd have to use this syntax : `trick_off <- dcast_off[,monthBy_off]` to remove the error.

But then you'll have to fix the plotting error, for example by plotting each month in a different color. For this, you'd better use the long data.frame (before the `dcast()`):

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        observe({

                trick_off <- dat_off[dat_off$variable %in% input$month,]
                output$plot_off <- renderPlot({
                        O <-ggplot(data = trick_off, aes(x=time_,y=value, color=variable)) +

                                geom_line(size = 2, alpha = 0.75) +
                                geom_point(size =3, alpha = 0.75) +

                                ggtitle("Boarding the Bus Ridership December 2015") +
                                labs(x="Time",y="Count")+
                                theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=32, hjust=0.5)) +
                                theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22))+
                                theme_classic()
                        O
                })

        })

})
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome by the way. So, the input$month gets the input from the UI and selects the rows of the `dat_off$variable` that all correspond to the input. If it has columns it's a dataframe, so  `data = trick_off` works, and there you can assign x, y and colour column wise?  So how are the different months separated and stored, if not by the group argument?  Sorry for all the questions, I'm just trying to understand how some of this works/

Comment: when you write `color=variable` you tell `ggplot()` there are several series.